# Serial Port interaction in bash

Tags: bash, serial-port, hex

I have a Serial Card Reader attached to COM1 `/dev/ttyS0`

I need to send a hex sequence and to receive an answer, then depending on the answer send another hex sequence.

Example:

```
#|/bin/bash
echo -en '\x02\x00\x02\x30\x31\x03\x02' > /dev/ttyS0

#I want something like:
while read -r line < /dev/ttyS0; do
   data = data + $line
done


if [$data = \x06 ]; then
   echo -en '\x05' > /dev/ttyS0
fi

done
```

can it be done?

Now I am trying this,
but no reply from the serial port.
If i use a terminal app it answers

```
function ReadCard(){

CardReply="reply.txt"
> $CardReply

filesize=$(wc -c < "$CardReply")

until [  $filesize -gt 0 ]; do
    filesize=$(wc -c < "$CardReply")
    echo "Size:$filesize"
    echo -en '\x02\x00\x04\x45\x30\x30\x32\x03\x72' > $SerialPort
    echo -en '\x05' > $SerialPort
    cat $SerialPort >> $CardReply
done

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Com1+Linux+

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for. Reading data by the Unix read command can be slow. You can save the input into a file and then use python or something faster to get the processing. Casually even sed is fine for the replace

Comment: and how do I save the input to a file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406039/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-serial-console-e-g-dev-ttys0-to-a-buffer-or-fi

Comment: Added a new code to the first post. Still nothing !! :(